# Verifyable logfile at customer site

Tags: digital-signature, public-key-encryption, sign

We want to create a logfile at customer site where

- the customer is able to read the log (plain text)
- we can verify at our site that the log file isn't manipulated

A few hundred bytes of *unreadable data* is okay. But some customers do not send us files where they can't verify that they do not contain sensible data.

The only reasonable option I see so far is to append a cryptographic checksum (e.g. `SHA256(SECRET_VALUE + "logtext")`). The `SECRET_VALUE` would be something hardcoded which is plain "[security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity)". Is there any better way?

We use the DotNet-library and I do not want to implement any crypto algorithm by hand if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use standard HMAC algorithm with a secret key to perform the checksum.

Using a secret key prevents in a simple way that the checksum can be regenerated directly. A hardcoded key could be extracted from code, but for your use case I think is enough

The result is a binary hash. To insert it into the text file encode the value as hexadecimal or base64, and ensure you are able to revert the process in server side so you can calculate the hash again with the original file.

You could use also a detached hash file to avoid modifying the log file

Comment: Thanks for pointing me on HMAC - saved me on reinventing the wheel

Answer (score 0):

## Target

- customer readable logfiles
- verifyable by our side
- minimum of binary data
- must work offline

## Options

- Public-Private-key-things... (RSA, ...)

  - would be secure
  - but only binary data
- Add a signature

  - We are not the first ones with that idea ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code )
  - DotNet supports that ( System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256 )
  - Key must be stored somewhere ... in source
  - Even with obfuscation: not possible to do so securely

## Trusted Timestamping

- again: we are not first ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_timestamping )
- needs connection to "trusted third party" (means: a web service)
- Build Hash + TimeStamp -> send to third party -> sign the data (public-private-key stuff) -> send back

## Best option so far

- Add a signature with HMAC
- Store the key in native code (not THAT easy to extract)
- Get code obfuscation running and build some extra loops in C#
- Every once in a while (5min?) put a signature into log **AND** into windows application log
- application log is at least basically secured against modification (read only)
  and it's collected by the our error report
- easy to oversee by customer (evil grin)